# Drive Api - large file stream in nodejs

Tags: node.js, google-api, stream, google-drive-api

**Drive Api - large file  stream in nodejs**

hello , I went to stream large file  from google drive to my website but I have issue  that...

```
app.get("/blog.mkv", (req, ress) => {
    const p38290token = new google.auth.OAuth2(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, REDIRECT_URI);
    p38290token.setCredentials({ refresh_token: token.acc });
    const p38290Id = google.drive({
        version: "v3",
        auth: p38290token,
    });
    try {
        p38290Id.files.get({
                fileId: "1OU3BXc4FmyRD0rCW9S4XFfVxIl48vy3v",
                alt: "media",
                // arraybuffer , stream , blob 
            }, { responseType: "stream" },
            (err, res) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err.message)
                    if (err.message === "invalid_grant") {
                        //  fatchToken(exportFile)
                    }
                } else {
                    res.data
                        .on("end", () => {
                            console.log("Done");
                        })
                        .on("error", err => {
                            console.log("Error", err);
                        })
                        .pipe(ress);
                }
            }
        )
    } catch (error) {

    }
})
```

when user come to /blog.mkv video is start stream but **user can't skip it (can't go forward or backwards )**  , what should I do ?

Comment: You have to support the ["Range" header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Range) on the incoming request.  That's how a media player requests a range of bytes from your media and how the player jumps ahead or goes back.  For a given request, you only send the range of bytes that it requests in the header.

Comment: it's by default  media player of chrome , how could I do ??

Comment: I'd suggest you do your research on supporting the range header on your server.  I gave you a link to get started on what it is.  If you have a more specific question about that, then please ask a more specific question.  Google drive itself appears to support the Range header [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-downloads#node.js).  So, your server would detect the Range header on the incoming request and would then request those specific bytes from Google Drive and set the appropriate headers on the response and send just those requested bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [repo](https://github.com/riccardomartinelli/Google-drive-video-streaming-nodejs) for streaming and downloading files from Google Drive.

#### Google-drive-video-streaming-nodejs

This is a small script in nodejs that allow you to watch a video stored in your Google Drive directly in your video player.

**Install**

You need only to install all the dependencies by typing this command:

```
npm install
```

**Usage**

Just type this command to startup the script.

```
node ./app.js
```

Now that the server is started you can start watching your video or download it.

**Streaming**

Paste this link into your player to start streaming the video.

```
http://127.0.0.1:9001/
```

**Download**

To download it, type this URL in a new browser tab.

```
http://127.0.0.1:9001/download
```

if you want you can specify the parameter `p`, that indicates as a percentage what portion of the video will be skipped. For example, to start downloading the video from starting from the halfway point you should use this link:

```
http://127.0.0.1:9001/download?p=50
```

You can even use the parameter `c` that indicates from what chunk the download must be started. To stop the downloading process use this URL:

```
 http://127.0.0.1:9001/download_stop
```